# T4 errors when run, but not when debugged

Tags: .net, t4, nswag

I'm trying to write a `.tt` file using NSwag, and when I run the Custom Tool, I get this error:

> Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NSwag.CodeGeneration, Version=6.6.6124.16498, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'NSwag.CodeGeneration, Version=6.6.6124.16498, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at NSwag.CodeGeneration.SwaggerGenerators.WebApi.WebApiAssemblyToSwaggerGenerator.WebApiAssemblyLoader.GenerateForController(String controllerClassName, String settingsData)
>      at NSwag.CodeGeneration.SwaggerGenerators.WebApi.WebApiAssemblyToSwaggerGenerator.GenerateForController(String controllerClassName) in C:\projects\nswag\src\NSwag.AssemblyLoader\SwaggerGenerators\WebApi\WebApiAssemblyToSwaggerGenerator.cs:line 59

However, when I debug the template, I do not. It runs correctly.

**Why would a T4 template run with debug but not normally?**

Here is what I've tried:

- Ensure the file (and related files) were not set to `Read-Only`.
- Check the Security settings for the `.dll` file. `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` and `Users` now have Full Control.
- Tried moving the DLL to `C:\Temp\`

Still doesn't work.

(This is not a question about FileNotFoundException, I understand what that means.)

Here's the start of my `.tt` file:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="T4Toolbox.tt" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Runtime" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ObjectModel" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\NJsonSchema.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\NSwag.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\NSwag.CodeGeneration.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Program Files (x86)\Rico Suter\NSwagStudio\NSwag.AssemblyLoader.dll" #>

<#@ import namespace="NSwag.CodeGeneration" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.CSharp" #>
<#@ import namespace="NSwag" #>
<#@ import namespace="NSwag.CodeGeneration.SwaggerGenerators" #>
<#@ import namespace="NSwag.CodeGeneration.SwaggerGenerators.WebApi" #>
<#@ import namespace="NSwag.CodeGeneration.Utilities" #>
<#@ import namespace="NSwag.Collections" #>
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem today.  I tried using the NSwag.MSBuild project.  I get that same FileNotFoundException when the afterbuild step runs.  Running the same command from the console works fine.  Then I tried using the assemblies from the NSwag.MSBuild package with a T4 template and got the same error that way as well.  For some reason the NSwag DLLs don't want to load from Visual Studio...

Comment: I think this is fixed with the latest version of NSwag (v7.7). Can you verify?